# How to bind data in controls and edit accordinly on dropdwonlist selectedindexchagned event in mvc4 razor using jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view for create/ edit data, in my view contains a dropdownlist control and two textboxes and two buttons [Create, Done Modifications], and my requirement is like below.

1. User should be able to select his/her name from dropdownlist which contains list user names. By default create button is visible and ‘Done Modifications’ button should be invisible.
2. Based on the dropdownlist item selection, if the record is already exists then show up his/ her data in DOB, Location textboxes then invisible Create button and able to update to the database by Done Modifications button.
3. Data population, edit, create, delete logic should be implement in Controller classes.
4. Above things should be happen in asynchronously, I don’t want to allow post backs on any events.

Thanks for your time!

Sridhar Goshika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

submit() method will submit the form by dropdownlist item selection

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProdID", null, new {@onchange="submit()" })
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the hourly rate you are going to pay for this?
This is a list of specifications given to you, that you pass on to us; It does not show any research, any code showing what you have done and where you are at. Moreover, there is no question there.